# Error building esp32-camera module: error: 'CONFIG_SCCB_CLK_FREQ' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: esp32

When building my esp32 based application that include esp32-camera module I get the following error:

```
.pio/libdeps/esp-wrover-kit/esp32-camera/driver/sccb.c:33:33: error: 'CONFIG_SCCB_CLK_FREQ' 
undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'CONFIG_XTAL_FREQ'?
   33 | #define SCCB_FREQ               CONFIG_SCCB_CLK_FREQ  /*!< I2C master frequency*/
```

Anyone know please what could be wrong here?

nothing worked so far, tried to check sdkconfig file but no clue how to find it under platformio based project.